# PostgreSQL: don't wait until INSERT is finished

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

Is there any way to write an INSERT command that wouldn't wait until the insertion is finished?
 I don't want the request to wait, the actual insertion can be delayed.

Comment: What is the client language/driver ?

Comment: Client language is Ruby

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to perform at least one call on a connection using `PQSendQuery` (and related functions) instead of `PGexec` without waiting for the result. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/libpq-async.html for details. If you want to issue several calls without waiting for the first to finish, you probably need some kind of queueing mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the client driver.

At the protocol level you don't have to wait; you can just send a Bind, Parse, Execute, Sync, and keep on doing what you want, then get around to consuming input from the server later.

libpq supports this to a limited degree via asynchronous operations.

Most drivers do not expose this functionality though. PgJDBC for example doesn't have a way to run an insert asynchronously (except in batch mode, where individual inserts within the batch are asynchronous, but it still waits for results of the whole batch at the end).

Something that'll work with any client driver is to have a separate thread do the insert. It can wait, and the rest of the app keeps on doing whatever else it wants to do.